# How to get the URL of Django page to reload?

Tags: html, django

I know there are ways to get it in aspx and php, but cant find it for Django.

I have an application (App1) and I load a page with a parameter (par1) with submit button from the database:

this is the url of the method:

```
...
path('load/', views.load, name='load'),
...
```

html part:

```
<form method="post" id="idForm" name="frm1" action = "/App1/save/#about" enctype="multipart/form-data">
....
      <input type="submit" name="load" id="load" value="Load"/>
```

I need something like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/App1/load/?par1=name1
```

to repeat the loading later, to send this link for other users. However it doesn't work, it loads some plain text/values.

Can someone help me to do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: in a simple way, I load a database data for year 2020 and want to send its url to my friend, to see database results for 2020. What is the link in this case?

Comment: What part does the form play in this?

Comment: plz sure whether it is exact about the action value.

Comment: what does it mean "it loads some plain text/values"? can you paste the result? it could be related to {% csrf_token %} , can we see what there is after <form method... ?

Comment: yes there is {% csrf_token %}